# How can I run database file before test suites in jasmine.json

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, jasmine

I'm using nodejs to create an end to end test suite for our API. Before each test runs, I need to insert database records for that test. Many of the tables in question do not use native auto-increment type fields for their primary keys.

(I know, bad database design. But I don't have control over that.)

Instead, I have a Postgres database server to connect.

As I begin to set up my tests, I am finding that my transactions are colliding with each other because of the asynchronous nature of javascript. Basically, the transactions are getting the same sequence numbers and then trying to commit on top of each other. So unique constraints are failing.

The first solution that comes to my mind (I'm open to others) is to just set up all of the database records before any tests run. But to my knowledge, Jasmine's beforeAll() function only applies to the file that it's in. I need a beforeAll() function that runs before all Jasmine tests run in all files everywhere.

Does Jasmine have something like that? If not, is there a way I can create a controller in nodejs that will set up the test cases in the database and then spawn jasmine programmatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a language feature. If you need to do sequentially executions, you'll need to execute `Promises` or `await`. As the language have a specific behavior, you'll need to play with this.